# How to filter points based on proximity while inserting into PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, sql

I have a large amount of locations that need to be inserted to a PostGIS database. However, I'd like to aggregate these points so that if there's already a location, say nearer than a kilometer, then to discard that point. I'd like a pointer or two on the appropriate query (or, if it can't be done in a reasonable way, then flame me...:)

I reckon it has to be done a bit like:

```
INSERT INTO locations VALUES (ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(54.55 26.33)')) 
IF ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(54.55 26.33)'), <all other points in "locations" should be evaluated here>) > 1000;
```

As most of the audience has probably understood by now, I'm not that bright when it comes to databases so don't be too harsh on me...

Comment: Are the locations stored in another table in postgres?

Comment: They are from a remote postgres db

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ST_Distance](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Distance.html) and convert to `geography` to test if there exists at least one location less than 1000 meters away:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) = 0 AS should_insert
FROM
    locations,
    (
        VALUES( SetSRID(MakePoint(54.55, 26.33), 4326) )
    ) AS new_value
WHERE
    center IS NOT NULL
AND
    ST_Distance( column1::geography, center::geography ) < 1000
LIMIT
    1
;
```

where `54.55, 26.33` is the value you want to test against `locations.center` in that example (`column1` is the name automatically assigned by the usage of `VALUES()`).

Then depending on the boolean result, you can decide to insert or not.

---

Otherwise, a more efficient method could be to insert all locations to a `temporary` (or even better `unlogged` if you have PostgreSQL 9.1) table, then let PostGIS cluster into cells, and use the result of this clustering to insert:

```
INSERT INTO locations (id, center)
SELECT
    ids[1] AS id,
    centers[1] AS center
FROM
(
    SELECT
        array_agg(id) AS ids,
        array_agg(center) AS centers
    FROM temporary_table
    GROUP BY ST_SnapToGrid( ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(center, 4326), 2163), 1000, 1000 )
) AS grouped
;
```

(this example works only with North American positions because of `SRID 2163`).